# Setting Document id by ReferenceField in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine

In Mongoengine I'm trying to set the id field of a Document by a `ReferenceField` of a Document located in a different database.

```
class User(Document):
    name = StringField()
    meta = {"db_alias": "user_db"}

class Credential(Document):
    id = ReferenceField(User)
    password = StringField()
    meta = {"db_alias": "credentials_db"}
```

I can do stuff like `u = User('someuser').save()`, with the problem that
`Credential(u, 'somepassword').save()` turns into

```
ValidationError (Credential:None) (Invalid Object ID: ['auto_id_0'] Field is required: ['id'])
```

Surely Mongodb only stores some ObjectIds and therefore I can't see why this should not be possible, but does MongoEngine support something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Document Ids](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/document-instances.html#document-ids)  must be unique so you need to set `primary_key` to `True` for the `id` field.

```
class Credential(Document):
    id = ReferenceField(User, primary_key=True)
    ...
```